# Compact Framework Remote Performance Monitor Error connecting to a device

Tags: compact-framework

I am trying to do a memory profile on a .Net CF app. It was originally compiled in 2.0, but I converted it to 3.5 so I can use the 3.5 CF PowerToys Remote Perf Mon. I am getting the following error message when trying to connect:

ActiveSync device: transport incompatible.

I am connecting via DMA through ActiveSync, should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason RPM doesn't work with the emulator before CF 3.5 SP1, so if you're targeting the emulator (which is seems you are) make sure you have the latest version of RPM and have manually deployed the RPM bits to the emulator.

Comment: Correct, I am targeting an instance running in an emulator. I may be slow today, but I don't see CF 3.5 SP1 available from Microsoft: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497280.aspx

Also, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "manually deploy the RDP bits to the emulator."

Comment: Take a look at hte section entitled "To set tup RPM by using ActiveSync" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404355.aspx